# Getting this issue in foundation email

Tags: node.js, npm

✓ New project folder created.
✗ Node modules not installed. Try running yarn install manually.

```
    *192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ clear
    
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ npm -v
    8.5.5
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ node -v
    v17.9.0
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ foundation -v
    Foundation CLI version 2.3.2
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ git --version
    git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ sudo npm install --global foundation-cli
    
    changed 192 packages, and audited 435 packages in 2s
    
    33 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
    
    To address all issues, run:
      npm audit fix
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$ foundation new --framework emails
    ? What's the project called? (no spaces) test3
    
              _____
             /     \
            /=   . |
        ___| ==  | /    Thanks for using Foundation for Emails!
       /   | ===  \     -------------------------------------------
       |   | ====  |    Let's set up a new project.
       /__/| =====  \   It shouldn't take more than a minute.
           (   __   )
            (O)  (O)
           (   __,  )
            \______/
    
    
    Downloading the project template...
    Done downloading!
    
    Installing dependencies...
    
    
    up to date, audited 3 packages in 7s
    
    2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
    
    Some issues need review, and may require choosing
    a different dependency.
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
    undefined
    
    There were some problems during the installation.
    
     ✓ New project folder created.
     ✗ Node modules not installed. Try running yarn install manually.
    
    Once you've resolved the above issues, run foundation watch while inside the test3 folder.
    
    192:email-templates sandeepsingh$*
```